Null al leer atributo de archivo XML en C#
Estoy desarrollando un programa para hacer backups de bases de datos tipo SQL y ACCESS, la cosa es que estoy guardando los datos del backup automático en formato XML y me esta dando un inconveniente al leer los atributos y demás datos que están en el archivo.
Estoy intentando leer el siguiente archivo XML:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Backup>
    <BackupAccess>
        <RutaBD DB="D:\JJ\JJfacil2019" NameDB="JJfacil2019" />
    </BackupAccess>
    <BackupSQL>
        <SQL SERVER=".\SQLEXPRESS" USER="sa" PASWORD="" CATALOGO="master" />
        <Databases>
            <Database>CursoV2</Database>
            <Database>D:\SQL\JJFACIL.MDF</Database>
            <Database>OTOsisProto</Database>
        </Databases>
    </BackupSQL>
    <ConfigBackup>
        <Root RutaBackup="D:\Proyecto C#\Curso\Curso\Formularios" HoraBackup="06:00 a. m." />
        <MaxBackup MaxOldMonth="0" MaxOldDays="15" />
    </ConfigBackup>
</Backup>

Cuando intento leer los atributos me devuelve NULL, este es el codigo que uso para leer, no esta completo pero es lo que hago una y otra vez a lo largo del codigo:
public void LeerXML(string lugar)
{
    XmlReader xmlBackup = XmlReader.Create(lugar);

    string srsDir = "";
    string BaD = "";
    string bakDir = "";

    while (xmlBackup.Read()) 
    {
        if ((xmlBackup.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlBackup.Name == "RutaBD"))
        {
            srsDir = xmlBackup.GetAttribute("DB");
            BaD = xmlBackup.GetAttribute("NameDB");
        }

        if ((xmlBackup.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlBackup.Name == "Root"))
        {
            bakDir = xmlBackup.GetAttribute("RutaBackup");
        }
    }

    this.BkCopiar(srsDir, bakDir, BaD);
}

Como veran uso el **XMLREADER**, tambien he ysado el **XmlDocument** y hace lo mismo.

probaste con la clase que lo hace solo? https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-8.0

He escrito un ejemplo que si lee los datos:
using System.Xml;

using XmlReader xmlBackup = XmlReader.Create("documento1.xml");

string srsDir = "";
string BaD = "";
string bakDir = "";

while (xmlBackup.Read())
{
    if ((xmlBackup.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlBackup.Name == "RutaBD"))
    {
        srsDir = xmlBackup.GetAttribute("DB");
        BaD = xmlBackup.GetAttribute("NameDB");
    }

    if ((xmlBackup.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlBackup.Name == "Root"))
    {
        bakDir = xmlBackup.GetAttribute("RutaBackup");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}; {1}; {2}", srsDir, bakDir, BaD);

Produce: D:\JJ\JJfacil2019; D:\Proyecto C#\Curso\Curso\Formularios; JJfacil2019
documento1.xml es tu ejemplo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Backup>
  <BackupAccess>
    <RutaBD DB="D:\JJ\JJfacil2019" NameDB="JJfacil2019" />
  </BackupAccess>
  <BackupSQL>
    <SQL SERVER=".\SQLEXPRESS" USER="sa" PASWORD="" CATALOGO="master" />
    <Databases>
      <Database>CursoV2</Database>
      <Database>D:\SQL\JJFACIL.MDF</Database>
      <Database>OTOsisProto</Database>
    </Databases>
  </BackupSQL>
  <ConfigBackup>
    <Root RutaBackup="D:\Proyecto C#\Curso\Curso\Formularios" HoraBackup="06:00 a. m." />
    <MaxBackup MaxOldMonth="0" MaxOldDays="15" />
  </ConfigBackup>
</Backup>

Es decir, no puedo reproducir el valor NULL.
Tal vez puedas presentar un ejemplo minimo pero completo que nos permita reproducir el problema.

Estuve revisando y resulta que cambiando el netframework trabajo de maravilla, estaba en el 4.0, luego cambie al 4.5 y leyó todo. realmente no entendí que tenia que ver el .net con eso pero por lo menos funciona. te daré el punto porque por lo menos me hiciste ver que no era el código el problema. disculpa responder tanto tiempo después
